# C++ RasPi - Segmentation fault while in endless loop

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

So I run an DS18S20 with an LCD Display.

I'm measuring my Room Temperature and displaying it on the LCD.

In said endless loop, I'm getting a Segmentation Fault after it ran 5-6 times. I've read that it must be a variable and got the suspicion that it's in my getTmp() function but don't know how to fix it.

I've been learning C++ for two weeks now and need your help.

Thank you in advance.

My Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <lcd.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
#define ever (;;)
//USE WIRINGPI PIN NUMBERS
#define LCD_RS  25               //Register select pin
#define LCD_E   24               //Enable Pin
#define LCD_D4  23               //Data pin 4
#define LCD_D5  22               //Data pin 5
#define LCD_D6  21               //Data pin 6
#define LCD_D7  14               //Data pin 7
void getTmp(string *y)
{
    ifstream file("/sys/bus/w1/devices/10-00080366745a/w1_slave");
    string f[2];
    if (file.is_open())
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        {
            getline(file, f[i]);
        }
    }
    string s = f[1];
    bool x = true;
    int i3 = 0, i2 = 0;
    while (x)
    {
        if (i2 <= 4 && i2 > 0)
        {
            y[i2 - 1] = s[i3];
            ++i2;
        }
        if (i2 > 4)
        {
            x = false;
        }
        if (s[i3] == '=')
        {
            i2 = 1;
        }
        ++i3;
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int microseconds = 5000;
    string b[4];
    string *y = b;
    int lcd;
    wiringPiSetup();
    const char *tmp;
    for ever
    {   
        getTmp(y);
        string t = "Temp = "+b[0]+b[1]+"."+b[2]+b[3]+"°C";
        tmp=t.c_str();
        lcd = lcdInit (2, 16, 4, LCD_RS, LCD_E, LCD_D4, LCD_D5, LCD_D6, LCD_D7, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        lcdPuts(lcd, tmp);
        cout << tmp << endl;
        usleep(microseconds);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It likely means one of your indices are out of bounds. Apply basic debugging techniques. Run your program in a debugger and check all array indices. If can't use debugger then good old debug print statements.

Comment: Can't really think that my getTmp goes out of bounds. It resets everytime it's started. And i added a sleep to let it finish.

Comment: Don't need to guess. Just use a debugger or print it out. You can't effectively debug anything beyond a trivial program just by staring at it and imagining what it may be doing.

Comment: Well i just try it then. Answering you when i found sth. suspicious :)

Comment: `for ever` Please never do that. Use `std::string::at` instead of `std::string::operator[]`, compile with debug symbols and have the exception tell you where exactly the error is. `lcd = lcdInit` is strange - you initialize the lcd each loop, why not initialize it once only?

Comment: Well this was it ty. I think the initialization might have messed with the Program. Now im initializing it at the start and it seems to work fine now. Ty

Comment: you are access something outside the array bounds. I suspect that s[i3] is the cause of the segmentation fault. i3 reaches to a value which makes s[i3] access is wrong. Debug your program with a debugger so you can spot the causality of the bug. A side note: take time to learn how to write a readable code. it will help you and others to investigate code problems easily.